# Find Members Primary Store

Tags: mysql

I am trying find a member's primary store within the last year, I am not sure of the best way to find it though.

For testing, I came up with this query to test on a single member (not sure if it is accurate or not):

```
select trn_soln,         -- Store Number
trn_trannbr,             -- Transaction Number
trn_purdate,             -- Transaction Date
left(trn_purdate, 7) dt, -- Year/Month
count(*) c,              -- Number of transactions per month at a particular store
43 / count(*) as average -- 43 = number of total results returned
from trans 
where trn_mbrid = @did
and trn_purdate >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR )
group by dt, trn_soln
order by average desc, trn_purdate desc;
```

So for example lets use the store **Target**, they have many locations, I would like to find the **Target** store that a member primarily shops at. I feel that I could just sort by `trn_soln desc` but that doesn't seem like it could accurate for this.

Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the primary store is based on the total number of transactions/store within the past year:

```
SELECT trn_soln, COUNT(*) AS TotalTrans
FROM trans
WHERE trn_mbrid = @did
  AND trn_purdate >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY trn_soln
ORDER BY TotalTrans DESC
LIMIT 1
```